# Is there a memory cycle when assigning variable with a function from another class?

Tags: swift

Is there a memory cycle in the code below? As i know `AnswersCollectionViewDelegate` has an implicit reference to `ViewController` because of closure `cellClickHandler` is a reference types but i cant mark `var cellClickHandler: ((Int) -> Void))?` as a `weak` because of error `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '(Int) -> Void'`

```
class AnswersCollectionViewDelegate: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var cellClickHandler: ((Int) -> Void))?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cellClickHandler(indexPath.Item)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    let answersDelegate = AnswersCollectionViewDelegate()

    @IBOutlet weak var answersCollectionView: UICollectionView!{
        didSet{
            answersDelegate.cellClickHandler = showNextPost
            answersCollectionView.delegate = answersDelegate
            answersCollectionView.dataSource = answersDelegate
        }
    }

    func showNextPost(answer: Int){
        //analyzeAnswer&showNextPost
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does, and it's a subtle thing to notice, so I think you've really understood how reference cycle happen. [There is some current work in the compiler to try to detect this and provide a warning](https://twitter.com/cocoaphony/status/1014248939611213825), but currently it's up to the developer to reason through this by hand.

The solution is to not use a function reference here but instead use a closure:

```
answersDelegate.cellClickHandler = { [weak self] self?.showNextPost(answer: $0) }
```

---

Regarding matt's comments below: properties with "delegate" in their name are almost always weak (or at most have a retain loop that ends after some operation completes). That said, I generally like the composition pattern you're doing here, and I don't think this is wrong (the one thing I'd probably do is pass the `cellClickHandler` in `AnswersCollectionViewDelegate.init` rather than setting it later). It's worth remembering, though, that when other developers see the word "delegate" in the property name, they're going to think it's weak and that can lead to bugs later. I'd probably call it `clickHandler` rather than `answersDelegate`.

Comment: Yes, that's better than my suggestion that the delegate reference be `weak`. But please do also tell him that the delegate reference should be `weak`! A strong delegate reference is not delegation.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable advice Rob, I realized how I should proceed!